# TinyMCE with paste plugin loses formatting in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, formatting, tinymce, paste

Greeting, everyone!

I have a webpage with a textarea that handles rich text via TinyMCE.  It worked fine when users pasted text into it from a variety of sources, but it had an issue when users tried to paste Word content into it (tons of extra XML tags added).  I fixed this using the "paste" TinyMCE plugin after getting advice from Stack Overflow posts.

Firefox works fine.  Users can now paste from Word or other sources (Notepad++, WinMerge, etc.) and the formatting is maintained.  However, in Chrome, pasting from Word works fine, but pasting from those other sources loses formatting and left-justifies everything.  A lot of users paste code snippets into this textarea and losing formatting makes it very difficult to read.

I'm using TinyMCE 3.5.10.  I tried 4.2.4 but I see the same behavior there.  Below is what my code looks like using 4.2.4.  My php source contains a textarea element with a "tinymce-test" id.

```
tinymce.init({

    selector: "#tinymce-test",
    height: "100px",
    width: "99%",
    toolbar: "bold, italic, undo, redo",
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    plugins: "paste"

});
```

My Firefox version is 39.0.3 and my Chrome version is 44.0.2403.155 m.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your options:

```
paste_webkit_styles: "color font-size"
```

This will allow it to retain color and font-size styles for webkit browsers. More info here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/paste/#paste_webkit_styles